# How to reconstruct MediaPipe landmark coordinates from extracted coordinate values?

Tags: mediapipe

I am able to extract the landmark coordinates from `results.pose_landmarks`. Now, I want to send it to another device and there, using the `x`, `y`, `z` and `visibility` values, the datatype will be reconstructed so as to build the pose on a frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the iterated values in a `list`. Then use this snippet below,

```
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
reconstructed = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList(extracted_points_list)
```

This will reconstruct the entire datatype.

Comment: Hi,I need to reconstruct the results.pose_landmarks. from the iterated lst. But doing this I am getting aTypeError.

   landmark_lst = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList(lst)
  TypeError: No positional arguments allowed